# Auto-direct emails to specific addresses on Google Form submit

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my first post so apologies in advance if I am posting to the wrong place or asking a question that has been answered elsewhere - go easy on me!

In a nutshell, I have a Google Form and a connected Google Sheet. I need to automate it so that, when a new form is submitted, an email is sent to a specific colleague (the student's supervisor). I have had a good go myself but am now totally stuck!

I have created [the form](https://forms.gle/4VaXYkxxqnnXZMqa7), [linked it to a sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DZTsqeeleETquGvuUf75r2BwEY3aSuxI2JP_JS6B0o8/edit?usp=sharing), written the code, added the trigger and tested by submitting a form. Nothing happened! No error messages, just... nothing!

Any advice hugely appreciated. I am very new to this and still taking baby steps.

The code I have cobbled together (which is probably full of errors!) is as follows:

```
function wa132657(e) {
//setup the spreadsheet


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //get the range from OnFormSubmit
  var range = e.range;
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the range is "+range.getA1Notation());//DEBUG

  // get the data for the range
  var response = row.getValues();



// get the supervisor name from the form submission
  var supervisor = response[0][1];
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Supervisor = "+supervisor);// DEBUG


// get the emails list
  var emailSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SupEmails");
  // get ALL the data from this sheet
  var emaildata = emailSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  // check how many rows of data
  var emailLastRow = emailSheet.getLastRow();
  // start the loop through the emails data
  for (var i=1; i<emailLastRow; i++){

    // if the supervisor is equal to SupervisorEmail
    if (supervisor == emaildata[i][0]){
      // there is a match
      //Next, get the email address
      var emailSupervisor = emaildata[i][1];
     Logger.log("DEBUG: supervisor = "+emaildata[i][0]+", email address: "+emailSupervisor);// DEBUG

      // Finally, send the Email.
      var theirName = e.values[2];
      var theirProgramme = e.values[3];
  var theAbsenceReason = e.values[8];
  var theAbsenceStart = e.values[5];
  var theAbsenceEnd = e.values[6];
  var subject = "Student Absence Report";
  var message = "New Absence Report: " + theirName + " \n Programme: " + theirProgramme; + " \n\n 

Reason for Absence: \n" + theAbsenceReason + " \n Start of Absence" + theAbsenceStart + "\n End of Absence:" + theAbsenceEnd;

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailSupervisor, subject, message);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which kind of trigger did you add?

Comment: Hello, thank you for looking at this. I added the trigger to run this function (wa132657) which runs at Head deployment, from spreadsheet, on form submit.

Comment: I have noticed that there is an incorrect couple of lines... the third section should read: // get the data for the range
  var response = range.getValues();

Comment: I've also noticed looking at the trigger report that the script is running and is executing successfully so the error must be somewhere in the script, I think. I have spent so long looking at this, trying to work out what is wrong that I am meeting myself coming backwards!

Comment: The form linked in your question is not accessible. Where exactly did you get stuck? Can you see any of the logs incorporated in your code? Keep in mind that the first response column is `[0]`, so probably you meant: `var supervisor = response[0][0];`?

Comment: Right, if the script has run, you should see the logs in the script, by choosing view logs. As a helpful debugging tip: build a function to run wa132657(e) by sending it an object literal with an range property. Then you can run the script in GAS, making it quicker to find errors.

Comment: I am getting somewhere now! I am getting emails, it is just the email body that I need to work on as the formatting is all a bit wappy but I can continue to chip away at that using the technique you have suggested, Hink.

Comment: I cannot tell you how grateful I am... all I needed to change was a single digit *sigh*

Comment: I am glad it helped. As for formatting, be aware that you can send emails with an HTML body:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)